# Inverse an irreducible matrix is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

A matrix $A\in GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ is irreducible iff there does not exist a permutation matrix $P$ such that
$P^TAP = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} B & C\\ 
 0 & D \end{array}\right]$.
There are many definitions for irreducibility of a matrix.

Is it true that $A^{-1}$is irreducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is immediate to see that if $A$ is reducible, then $A^{-1}$ is reducible as well since

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} B & C\\ 
 0 & D \end{array}\right]\left[ \begin{array}{cc} B^{-1} & -B^{-1}CD\\ 
 0 & D^{-1} \end{array}\right]=I.$$

Since the argument is reversible, then we have that if $A^{-1}$ is reducible, then $A$ is too.

Therefore, you can conclude that $A$ is irreducible if and only if $A^{-1}$ is.